# Having problems with regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have wrote a regular expression in Javascript in an ASP-file.

```
var re = new RegExp("<h2>Dollarkurs\sAktuell<\/h2><\/div>"+
        "<div[^>?]+><div><table>"+
        "<colgroup><col[^>?]+><col><col[^>?]+><\/colgroup>"+
        "<tbody><tr><td[^>?]+>Kurs<\/td>"+
        "<td[^>?]+>([^\s^<?]+)\s*<span[^>?]+>[^>?]+><\/span>"+
        "<span[^>?]+><\/span>"+
        "<\/td><\/tr><tr>"+
        "<td[^>?]+>Kurszeit<\/td><td[^>?]+>"+
        "^(([0-1]?[0-9])|([2][0-3])):([0-5]?[0-9])(:([0-5]?[0-9]))?$\sUhr"+
        "<\/td><\/tr><tr>"+
        "<td[^>?]+>Kursdatum<\/td><td[^>?]+>"+
        "([0-9\.]+)<\/td>", "gmi");

    var mres = re.exec(htmlTxt);
```

htmlTxt is(a part of webpage [www.finanzen.net/devisen/dollarkurs](http://www.finanzen.net/devisen/dollarkurs)):
[**HTML CODE**](http://www.44085497.com/linshi/html.txt)
[image]

But the Object mres is null. How to solve this problem? I need the Object mres.

```
What I need:
mres[0] is 1,0947
mres[1] is 16:00:00
mres[2] is 28.04.2015
```

THX a lot!

Comment: Why don't you just use jQuery find?

Comment: Can you paste the text instead of an image? I'd be helpful to test

Comment: Because i maintain an old project. There is no jQuery Lib...

Comment: It would've been much better if you had put the actual html code in your question instead of a screenshot.

Comment: [You cant parse html with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/219661)

Comment: @Fede I try to do that

Comment: @Fede the link "HTML CODE" please

Comment: @YingStyle can you put the code to regex101.com, I cannot access to that link because of proxy issues

Comment: thank you!  I check my regex now in regex101.com

Answer (score 0):

@Fede

I have found the problem.

The regex for ***+0,58%*** and ***16:00:00 Uhr*** are wrong.

for ***16:00:00 Uhr***

```
solution: ^(([0-1]?[0-9])|([2][0-3])):([0-5]?[0-9])(:([0-5]?[0-9]))?\sUhr
```

for ***+0,58%***

```
solution: (-)?\d+\,?\d{0,2}%
```